# Checkmarx highlight code as sqlinjection vulnerability

Tags: java, security, sql-injection, checkmarx

Checkmarx indicates the following code snippet as a sql injection vulnerability.

In the checkmarx report descibe the below code snippet as shown below

> "gets user input from the readLine element. This  element’s value then
>   flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated
>   This may enable an SQL Injection attack"

For brevity I havent included full text.

```
InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try{                    
                        ClassPathResource defaultReports = new ClassPathResource(dbVendor + "/sql_inserts.sql");

                        isr = new InputStreamReader(defaultReports.getInputStream());
                        br = new BufferedReader(isr);

                        c = session.connection();
                        String sqlLine = null;
                        while((sqlLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sqlLine = sqlLine.trim();
                                Statement st = null;
                                try{
                                    st = c.createStatement();
                                    st.execute(sqlLine);
                                }catch(SQLException e){

                                }catch(Exception e){

                                }finally{
                                    if (st != null)
                                        st.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

//sql_inserts.sql file contain set of insert statements

I want to convert above code to checkmarx friendly way.After that checkmark should not be highlighted the code snippet as high sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

> A SQL injection attack consists of insertion or "injection" of a SQL query via the input data from the client to the application.

Source: [SQL Injection - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

---

In your code, as shown by the Checkmarx tool, a SQL query `sqlLine` is executed, completely unchecked. We can see that it comes from a stream of some sort, but the question is what exactly is the source of these queries.

If the stream is under your complete control, which means you know exactly what it contains, you can consider it not-exploitable. Examples of such cases can be using hard-coded queries or choosing from (or comparing to) a defined "whitelist" - a known good/allowed list of queries. **IMPORTANT: Only if the query strings are controlled by 100% trusted sources it can be considered not exploitable**

If the stream or the queries themselves can somehow be controlled/changed/affected by a user, you should consider the queries untrusted and unsafe. In this case, steps to prevent SQL injection must be taken. The way you build your queries is not clear from your code snippet so a specific recommendation cannot be suggested here. You should carefully go over the prevention methods in the [OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and choose the right one for you.

Good luck!

Comment: "what exactly is the source of these queries" - the classpath, according to the code posted.